# ios recognizing gestures simultaneously with object handling

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

Is it possible to recognize gestures and touches simultaneously when interacting with a UIKit object.  For example, when a user is scrolling through a slider or pickerview, could I also be handling a swipe gesture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your view controller to be the delegate of your gestures, you can implement:

```
- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

I'm not sure if you're also trying to have the view handle touch events separately, but if you are, I'd recommend subclassing UIGestureRecognizer and handle touch events there.

Comment: The object in question was a UIViewPicker.  When handling the picker, ios does not categorize the interaction as a gesture recognizer so that method won't work.  I think I would need to override the class of the object.

Comment: I assume you mean UIPickerView and if what you say is true, then yes, I suppose you'd need to subclass it.  But I'm surprised it doesn't work.  UIPickerView is a fairly standard control and I can't see why they would handle touches directly in that view rather than the standard gesture recognizers.  I've not had a problem with other UIKit views, including UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSThread or NSTimer to create a new thread where you can create another process which will run parallel to main thread of the application