# How to determine direction of UIPickerView rotation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipickerview

In my code I need to know in what direction my UIPickerView rotate at this moment.
Can anybody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sublcass UIPickerView and add the standard touch handling events.  The UIPickerView is composed of nine subviews, one of which is a UIScrollView.  Use the [gesture recognition api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855145/ios-recognizing-gestures-simultaneously-with-object-handling) to handle the events.

Example of subclassing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567805/responding-to-touchesbegan-in-uipickerview-instead-of-uiview/6591975#6591975).